# Find Match In Header & Offset To X Number Of Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a way to populate an amortization schedule as per below.

[image: Amort schedule]

The formula I am using currently is:

```
=IF($B2=$1:$1,$A2/$C2," ")
```

However, this only fills the first point ("start point"), what I am trying to do is offset this based on the amortization period. The desired result is:

[image]

Is this possible with a formula - or do I need to try my luck with VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in these formulas:

D2: `=IF(D$1=$B2,$A2/$C2,"")`

E2: `=IF(E$1=$B2,$A2/$C2,IF(COUNT($D2:D2)<$C2,D2,""))`

D2 gets filled down in just the D column.

E2 gets filled right across all remaining columns and then filled down.

Comment: It may be a little less intuitive, but it's been simplified. There's actually no need to test for D2 being populated, as it can just copy blanks up to the first value.